# Articles in English, the use of "the" and "a"

Tags: articles

The following are sentences I picked up from newspaper articles.

1. "A smiling Ichiro Suzuki(a popular baseball player) talked at the interview through an interpreter."
2. "The 22-year-old XXX (a popular golf player) is a 12-time champion on the International Golf tour."

I don't understand why they put an article "a"  in the sentence 1)  and "the" in the sentence 2).  Please help me understand why.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: There can be "a smiling X" and "a non-smiling X", but only one "22-year-old X".

Comment: Related: [“the average person” vs “an average person”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122006/the-average-person-vs-an-average-person)

Comment: Related: [Why is it ‘A God,’ not ‘God' in Mark Sanford’s “I want to acknowledge a God not just of second chances, but third, fourth, eighth chances”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113619/21286)

Comment: Good question, but it has been already answered several times

Answer (score 2):

The use of "*a [adjective] [person]*" usually indicates that the descriptor being applied is transitory or changeable. In this construction, we view the person a member in the *set of all possible modes* that the person can be:

> When we arrived, we met a smiling Ichiro Suzuki.
>
> When we arrived, we met a hungry Ichiro Suzuki.
>
> When we arrived, we met a confused Ichiro Suzuki.

However, you wouldn't normally say:

> A tall Ichiro Suzuki greeted us.
>
> A 22-year-old Ichiro Suzuki greeted us.

Height and age are (more or less) fixed attributes. If you do use the "*a [adjective] [person]*" construction with a mostly-fixed property, you call attention to the mutability of the property. For example:

> John Smith hasn't always been such a clean-cut fellow... I still remember that night ten years ago, when I saw a 17-year-old John Smith being hauled by the neck into a police car.

Here, we mean *I saw the 17-year-old form of John Smith*, from the set of John Smith at all his possible ages. Or:

> I my cousin Kenny has always been a little short for his age, so I was a little shocked when a six-foot-tall Kenny greeted me at the airport -- the kid had certainly hit his growth spurt!

Here, again, we call attention to the mutability of Kenny's height and refer to a *particular form of Kenny* that is six feet tall.